# AngularJs - how move from $.ajax to $http

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

For testing purpose (in order to use $httpBackend) I want to convert my Service to use **$http** instead of jQuery **$.ajax**.

My current service looks like this

```
app.service('myService', function() {
  return { 
    getUserById: function(id) {
      return $.ajax({
        url: ...,
        type: 'GET'
        ...
      })
      .fail(function()){}
});
```

So, the **Service handles the fail** and I let the client, that calls the method, to handle the rest, like this:

```
myService.getUserById(123)
  .done(function(data){
    // use data
  })
  .always(function()){
   // do stuff
  }
```

Now, using the Angular **$http** I'm not sure how to reproduce the same behavior. 
This is the usage from the [AngularJS website](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
})
.then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

How can I "split" the success and the error callback functions between client and service?

Answer (score 0):

Your service would look something like this:

```
app.service('myService', function() {
  return { 
    getUserById: function(playerId){
     return $http.get('/someUrl/' + playerId, config).then(
      function(res){
       // handle any factory / decorating logic
       return res;
      }),
      function(err){
       //handle error
       return "error"; 
      }
    }
 }
});
```

The client code would look like this:

```
myService.getUserById(123).then(
 function(success){
  // use data
 },
 function(error){
  // handle error
 }
)
```